# Android, webview IntersectionObserver is not triggered on some devices

Tags: android, angular, webview, intersection-observer

My Android application embeds a webview, the webview is written in Angular10. The webview displays a list of items using infinite scroll. A chunk of the data is displayed and when `IntersectionObserver` is triggered a new chunk of data is displayed.

It works fine on some of my devices (for example Google Pixel 4, Samsung S10e) but on some device (for example Sony Xperia XZ, Samsung TabS2) only the first chunk is displayed, the `IntersectionObserver` is not triggered and other chunks are not displayed.

The Android application computes the available space for the webview, if I slightly change the available space (for example by substracting 5 pixels) then the `IntersectionObserver` is triggered. This does not work for all devices.

The place available on the screen for the webview is computed as follow:

```kotlin
private fun computeWebViewHeight() {
    val displaymetrics = DisplayMetrics()
    activity.windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(displaymetrics)
    val deviceHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels

    webView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        override fun onGlobalLayout() {
            webView.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)

            val actionBar = activity.findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.action_bar)

            webView.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                deviceHeight - actionBar.height - statusBarHeight // - 5 
            )
        }
    })
}
```

I first thought that the available space computed was erroneous but if I compare with the effective height of the webview then both measurement matches, that is the height of the webview corresponds to the available space.

Have you already experienced such behaviour ? Do you have any idea where the problem comes from ?

Comment: I have found a workaround to the problem: I have added empty lines in the html that displayed the list. The intersection observer is then always triggered when needed, and it works on all devices (that I could test on). The only downside is that there is empty lines at the end of the lines